# how to write a complex search query in elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, where-clause

im using laravel, and elasticsearch
and now i want to write a search query:
but my problem is i dont know how to write a query like this : 
**(preference_1 = Apples OR preference_2 = Bananas) AND (preference_1 = Apples OR preference_2 = Cherries) AND preference_1 = Grapefruits**

i know how to write  : **(preference_1 = Apples AND preference_2 = Bananas) OR (preference_1 = Apples AND preference_2 = Cherries) OR preference_1 = Grapefruits**

with one should and multiple must it could happen .. but i dont know how to do the inverse of that?

```
"query" => [
"bool" => [
            "should" => [[
                "bool" => [
                    "must" => [[
                        "match" => [
                            "preference_1" => "Apples"
                        ]
                    ], [
                        "match" => [
                            "preference_2" => "Bananas"
                        ]
                    ]]
                ]
            ], [
                "bool" => [
                    "must" => [[
                        "match" => [
                            "preference_1" => "Apples"
                        ]
                    ], [
                        "match" => [
                            "preference_2" => "Cherries"
                        ]
                    ]]
                ]
            ], [
                "match" => [
                    "preference_1" => "Grapefruit"
                ]
            ]]
        ]
]
```

i want to know how to write this one :
(preference_1 = Apples OR preference_2 = Bananas) AND (preference_1 = Apples OR preference_2 = Cherries) AND preference_1 = Grapefruits

i read elasticsearch doc, but i did not find anything, or some example..

thanks for your help.

Comment: You can nest should inside of must

Comment: yes.. but i have to create a dynamic array of should and must in my code.. depends of some if and else..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` for `and` (non-scoring filter queries) in same way you used `should`.

```
{:query=>
  {:bool=>
    {:must=>[{:match_all=>{}}],
     :filter=>
      [{:bool=>
         {:should=>
           [{:term=>{:preference_1=>"Apples"}},
            {:term=>{:preference_2=>"Bananas"}}],
          :minimum_should_match=>1}},
       {:bool=>
         {:should=>
           [{:term=>{:preference_1=>"Apples"}},
            {:term=>{:preference_2=>"Cherries"}}],
          :minimum_should_match=>1}},
       {:bool=>
         {:should=>[{:term=>{:preference_1=>"Grapefruits"}}],
          :minimum_should_match=>1}}]}}}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
but it didnt worked for me.. 
did i should use match_all query to get my response? or without it, it will be ok?

and in my code i have to make query dynamically.. i mean i have to add some must and some should in some if and else..

so i want a way to create an array of must and should.. and at the end of my code send that to elasticsearch.

Comment: i also create a generic query using if and else. So if there is a search_term i dont use match_all otherwise I add match_all. What do u have in your if/else, I do an if/else like this: `if operator == 'or' then bool[:should] = [] else if operator == 'and' then bool[:filter] = []`. After doing this I add query in should or filter

Comment: ok after many try i wrote my query using your suggestion..thanks

  but i have another problem now!
i have some query in bool => filter... and some in filter.. 

but my query result just show filter result.. and ignore my bool => [ filter => ..] result..

what can i do now to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

my query is just like yours.. but i delete 'must' from that..to make it work

```
body => [
  query => [
     bool => [
        filter => [
        [
           bool => [
               should => [
                   [term => [preference_1 => "Apples" ]],
                   [term => [preference_2 =>"Bananas"  ]]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
           bool => [
              should => [
                [term => [preference_1 => "Apples" ]],
                [term => [preference_2=>"Cherries"]]
              ]
            ]
        ],
        [
           bool => [
              should => [
                [term => [preference_1 => "Grapefruits"]]
              ]
           ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
],
filter => [
 [
  term => [field3 => "dog" ]
 ]
]
```

but 
when i active filter query ... elastic ignore my body query.